# Is it possible to run an app for device in Android Wear(Moto 360)?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app for a device in **android wear**. But when I give command to open the app, it only opens in the device.

Is it possible to run an app for device in Android Wear(Moto 360)?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this before, only heard it from Google developers via youtube. I hope you find this usfull.

Does your app really support Android Wear ? You have to optimize you app to run on Android Wear.

How to install wearable apps:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

How to developer wearable apps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbSwhmquRb0
Check this out:
https://www.android.com/wear/check/

Official Google docs about wear designing:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html

Comment: I came to know that we can install .apk files for any applications into Android Wear using ADB command. I tried it and installed some apps. Some small applications worked fine, some worked partially, some installed but crashed while playing and some applications failed during installation.  Is any additional requirement to play applications in Android Wear  by directly installing .apk?